# Visual studio loading solution very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution, ngen

I have a solution with several projects. Loading this solution takes usually not more than 1 min. However few days ago, time of loading the solution increase to several minutes. I have try to do some thing which I found on the Internet:
-disable all add-ins
-clear all suo files.
-clear list of recent projects.
But this do not work. I install the ProcessMonitor and I noticed that during loading my solution devenv make huge amount of request to files placed in: C:\Patches\Default\devenv.exe and C:\Patches\NativeImage\devenv.exe is this correct? Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have a quite similar problem with visual studio 2015, lots of files created under random folder and slowing down visual studio ... but I found out it was not visual studio

Process seemed to be devenv.exe however the files are created because I used fusion log viewer to troubleshoot assembly loading , and forgot to stop logging.

how to fix: open fuslogvw as admin, and disable logging